# How do I Query XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee

In .net I would use LINQ to XML to query an xml document with linq. Is there anything similar in Java EE?

I have a large xml file with state,city,town names that i need to use for cascading dropdowns. So I am looking for the best way to retrieve this data.

Thanks

Comment: Java never has anything as convenient as .Net.  _sigh_

Comment: Wait for Java 8: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8

Comment: @Simon: That doesn't mention anything about XML.

Comment: Yes but about lambda (LINQ is based on lambda)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) to select the relevant data using [javax.xml.xpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html)

It is a more standard way and you'll be able to use the same `XPath` expression in many programming languages (unlike LINQ)

You can see a nice example for XPath [here](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/xpath-tutorial.aspx) as well.

Comment: To complement this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java